# Django authentication with custom model UserProfile (not builtin User)

Tags: django, django-authentication

For my needs builtin model User is not enough...
So I have my own model UserProfile and I want make authentication on site through this model (UserProfile does not inherit from User model and not related to it at all).

But builtin authentication uses model User.

So I want to understand how can I change that, so authentication use my model UserProfile with all auth features???

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to create your own [Authentication Backend](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/authbackends/) to tell Django to create a UserProfile instead a User.

In this examples, the user model is extended so you will have to adapt it to your own requirements:

[Example 1](http://nigel.jp/2011/06/django-user-authentication-and-extending-the-user-model/)

[Example 2](http://www.kolios.dk/2010/01/22/how-to-extend-django-user-class-and-change-authentication-middleware/)